# Set CSS of React component to value received from server side

Tags: css, reactjs

There is sample component

```
//...
render () {
    return <div 
        className="col-sm-1" 
        style={{ "backgroundColor": "#FFF6F2", "minWidth": "8em", "minHeight": "4em"}} 
        onClick={()=>{this.showDiv('low_intent')}}> 
        <span id="low_intent"></span>
    </div>
}
```

`onClick` of a `div` should change `div`'s width

Comment: Can you share some code with us so we can be more helpful?

Comment: I have added please look into it

Answer (score 0):

Every HTML tag has `style` attribute which you can manipulate in runtime.

Below example set `div` width to `'10px'` when clicked on it.

```
import * as React from 'react';

class Component1 extends React.Component {

    constructor () {
        super ();
        this.state = {
            divWidth: ''
        }
    }

    setDivWidth(intent) {
        this.setState({divWidth: intent});
    }

    render () {
        return <div 
            className="col-sm-1" 
            style={{ "backgroundColor": "#FFF6F2", "minWidth": "8em", "minHeight": "4em", "width": this.state.divWidth}}} 
            onClick={()=>this.setDivWidth('10px')}> 
            <span id="low_intent"></span>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: <div className="col-sm-1" style={{ "backgroundColor": "#FFF6F2", "minWidth": "8em", "minHeight": "4em"}} onClick={()=>{this.showDiv('low_intent')}}> <span id="low_intent"></span></div>

Comment: onClick of a div. Modal has to trigger.

Answer (score 0):

Add below code in render before returning react element

```
objStyle = {
    minWidth: this.state.minWidth || “8em”,
    minHeight: this.state.minHeight || “4em”
}
```

Update style attribute as mention below

```
style={objStyle}
```

Now whenever you receive width or height from server you can update in state.

Comment: There are 4 div which are divided into intent level as low, medium, high and highest. The one which is having more value let's say 8 has to be having more width rather than rest of 3 intents.